# Issue with python3 in neovim

Tags: python-3.x, neovim, neovim-plugin

I just switched to neovim and I am having troubles setting it up: when I do the command :echo has('python3') it returns 0 even tho I installed pynvim using pip. what should I do it is to be able to use vimspector debugger.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: You could check your install/configuration for Python provider with `:checkhealth` => section `Python 3 provider`